# 'Year Obtained from education' on CV meaning

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, vocabulary, sentence, phrase-meaning

So I am filling out a CV and answering about my education, when it comes up 'year obtained' I have never come across this on a CV before and if I have it hasn't been worded this way. Could someone help me? I am confused about whether it asking me the year I started or left,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

"Year obtained" refers to the year that you received your degree or certification, when you completed your course of education. If you never completed the course, I suppose you could put your last year, but be careful that you don't misrepresent yourself as having a qualification that you didn't complete.